# Perl retrieving value from PostgreSQL database returning undef

Tags: perl, postgresql

On my User Preferences page I have a perl script:

```
my $prefs = USystems::UserPrefs->new($user->userid);
```

which calls on:

```
sub new {
    my $self = shift;
    my $class = ref($self) || $self;
    my $userid = shift;

    $self = bless {}, $class;
    $self->{dbh} = USystems::DB->new;

    if($userid) {
        $self->userid($userid);
        $self->__populate;
    }

    return $self;
}

sub __populate {
    my $self = shift;

    my $sth = $self->{dbh}->prepare("select prefid, value from user_preferences where userid=?");
    $sth->execute($self->userid);
    while(my $href = $sth->fetchrow_hashref()) {
        $self->value($href->{PREFID}, $href->{VALUE}, $href->{OTHERS_POST});
    }
    $sth->finish();
}
```

Which is suppose to return all of the user's current preferences from the table in the database.

When I dump out `$prefs` I get the following:

```
  'USERID' => 1286,
  'PREFS' => {
          '1' => {
                   'VALUE' => 4,
                   'OTHERS_POST' => undef
                  }
              },
```

The problem is my $prefs is returning `undef` for `OTHERS_POSTS` when it should be returning a "1". I expect the problem to be involved with the subs `new` and `__populate`but I'm not very experienced with Perl to be able to locate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't selecting OTHERS_POST as a column, are you? It can't be anything other than undefined.

Comment: I added `others_posts` into the `my $sth = $self->{dbh}->prepare("select prefid, value, others_posts from user_preferences where userid=?");` line and ran the code but still got undef. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes. In that case dump the `$href` - it's clearly not got the values you are expecting.

Comment: Eventually identified the problem that was in another function. Thanks for the initial guidance